# Datetime datatype in MySQL making error

Tags: mysql, insert

I have created a table using below mensioned query in MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE Pat_Visit (PatientID INT(16), FOREIGN KEY(PatientID) REFERENCES patient_demo(PatientID),Visit_DateTime DATETIME,Visit_Title VARCHAR(6),
DoctorID INT(16),FOREIGN KEY(DoctorID) REFERENCES Doctor(DoctorID));
```

and i have tried to add some data using query given below.

```
  INSERT INTO Pat_Visit(PatientID,Visit_DateTime,Visit_Title,DoctorID) VALUES (100001,10/24/11 10:00 AM,'PAIN IN JOINTS',920001);
```

but it ios throwing error. I dont know what is the problem here.can anybody help me please...

Comment: This question shows little effort. You didn't even read the error message.

Comment: i read the error message.But i could not understand the problem

Comment: @Rosa error msg is:You have an error in your SQL syntax;check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '10:00,'PAIN IN JOINTS',920001)' at line 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instruction:

```
INSERT INTO Pat_Visit(PatientID,Visit_DateTime,Visit_Title,DoctorID) 
VALUES (100001,'2011-10-24 10:00:00','PAIN IN JOINTS',920001);
```

You could convert your date like this:

```
STR_TO_DATE('10/24/11 10:00 PM','%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p')
```

So the instruction is:

```
INSERT INTO Pat_Visit(PatientID,Visit_DateTime,Visit_Title,DoctorID) 
    VALUES (100001,STR_TO_DATE('10/24/11 10:00 PM','%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p'),'PAIN IN JOINTS',920001);
```

Extracted from the [Mysql datetime documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)

> MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
>   format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31
>   23:59:59'.

Comment: it is working...but the thing is i have to add data in the same format.. i mean dd/mm/yy format.is it possible?can you help me?

Comment: You have to convert it into YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format before insert.

Comment: Fred i am migrating excel database to MySQL.so it is difficult to convert bulk data into this format.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not post the error is a little bit hard to debug. Anyway:

1. You should write the datetime between single quotes
2. This is the typical format of a datetime: 2011-02-23 17:34:11

Answer (score 0):

Put the date in quotes, and reformat the time and date:

```
INSERT INTO Pat_Visit(PatientID, Visit_DateTime, Visit_Title, DoctorID) 
VALUES (100001, '2011-10-24 10:00', 'PAIN IN JOINTS', 920001);
```

Also, make the Visit_Title column much larger. 6 characters is not long enough to store 'PAIN IN JOINTS'.

Comment: Updated for formatting problem. Also take note - the Visit_Title column is far too small. Use Fred's method to fix your date.