# Error with datetime insertion

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm trying to insert a datetime in my table, but I can't figure why it isn't working. I'm running the following query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dynamic_pricing ;
CREATE TABLE dynamic_pricing(
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    time_start  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    time_stop TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    change_ratio REAL NOT NULL
    -- day_of_week INT(1)
);

INSERT INTO  dynamic_pricing(id,time_start,time_stop,change_ratio) 
VALUES(1,DATETIME('2000-01-01 00:00:00'),DATETIME('2000-01-01 00:00:02'),2);
```

I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077744/datetime-datatype-in-mysql-making-error), only to get

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the 
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near '('2000-01-01 00:00:00'),DATETIME('2000-01-01 
00:00:02'),2)' at line 2
```

What's wrong with this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your value is defined as DATETIME() but you could use 
`INSERT INTO dynamic_pricing VALUES ('2017-06-03 21:30:03' )` 
instead.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are defaulting two values, you don't need to insert them.  I would suggest:

```
INSERT INTO  dynamic_pricing(time_stop, change_ratio) 
    VALUES('2000-01-01 00:00:02', 2);
```

Then, the `DATETIME()` is unnecessary (is it even a function?).  [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c3d4/1) is a SQL Fiddle example.

Comment: Yeah, thats not a function. My bad =/. Removing it solves the issue

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT INTO  dynamic_pricing(id,time_start,time_stop,change_ratio) 
VALUES(1,'2000-01-01 00:00:00','2000-01-01 00:00:02',2);`